# How to best handle multiple related templates in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am trying to make a panel to display some data I get from an API. I have decided that XTemplates are probably the best way of handling this. However, I would like the panel to be well organized and flexible like other ext.js elements. So what I came up with is multiple templates in one panel that all run off of the same data. Here is an example of what I am thinking:

```
{
        title: 'Hello',
        layout: 'hbox',
        data: {
            data1: "test",
            data2: "42",
            data3: "fish"
        },
        items: [{
            tpl: "<div>This is some data, {data1}</div>",
            xtype: "panel",
            flex: 1
        }, {
            tpl: "<div>This is more data: {data2}, plus it has a friend {data3}</div>",
            xtype: "panel",
            flex: 2
        }]
    }
```

So my question is, what is the best way of updating all the templates in a panel when I get new data, or is there a better way of handling this whole problem than the way I am attempting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `attribute` to the components that all share the same data so that you can query by that attribute.

For instance:

```
items:[{
   xtype:'panel',
   tpl: 'template1',
   custom: 'sharedData'
},{
   xtype:'panel',
   tpl: 'template1',
   custom: 'sharedData'
}]
```

And then you can `query` by that `attribute` and iterate through the results modifying there data all at once:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[custom="sharedData"]').forEach(function(comp){
    //manipute the component's data
});
```

*Another Option:*

If the tpl's are actually all in the same `items` array you could potentially make just one `tpl` with all the info.

Comment: If I make one tpl, then I can't easily accomplish the hbox with different flex values on the children affect can I?

Comment: @skycon i think you could add the classes to the divs that sencha adds for hbox etc however, yeah that would probably be complicated.

Comment: I think I will probably end up going with your first solution, it will be easier to maintain.